# ASP.NET C# WebSocket

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, websocket, json.net

I have created an ASP.NET C# project which consists of a web form and a WebSocket handler. I would like to send 2 data (name & price data) from the web form in JSON string format to the WebSocket handler. Here is the code snippet in the web form:

```
            ws.onopen = function()
           {

               var name = "Client Product";
               var price = 10.8;
               ws.send(JSON.stringify(name));
               ws.send(JSON.stringify(price));
              alert("Message is sent...");
           };
```

In the WebSocket handler's OnMessage(string) method, I would like to retrieve the 2 data sent by the web form and deserialize the 2 data to c# format. Here is the code snippet in the WebSocket handler:

```
     public override void OnMessage(string message)
    {
        string serverName="";
        string serverPrice = "";

        serverName = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(message);
        serverPrice = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(message);

    }
```

However, under the WebSocket handler's onMessage(string) method, both the variable serverName and serverPrice would be assigned as "Client Product". I want the variable serverPrice to be assigned as "10.8", instead of "Client Product".

Can somebody please tell me how I could achieve that? WILL really appreciate if you could help me :) Thank You :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send multiple pieces of data in a single JSON message, you'll need to combine them into an object.  Try it like this:

On the client:

```
ws.onopen = function()
{
    var obj = {
        name: "Client Product",
        price: "10.8"
    };
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
    alert("Message is sent...");
};
```

On the server:

```
public override void OnMessage(string message)
{
    MyData obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(message);

    string serverName = obj.Name;
    string serverPrice = obj.Price;

    ...
}

public class MyData
{
    // Important: these JsonProperty attributes MUST match
    // the names of the properties in the client object

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Brian :) You save my life :)